# Why is my device not showing the table?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am new to Android.
I am trying to show a scrollable table.
The XML visualizer on Android Studio shows it fine, but my device is not showing it.
In my device, I can only see the first `TextView`(routine_heading).
What should I do to overcome this problem?

Below is the XML code I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/routine_heading"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/routine_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:fillViewport="false">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tlGridTable"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="10-10:50"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="10:50-11:40"
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="11:40-12:30"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="12:30-1:20"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="2:35-3:20"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="3:20-4:00"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="4:00-4:50"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                </TableRow>
             </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you trying to create horizontal scroll or vertical scroll??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are Setting column size to stretch to its parent! where its parent is a HorizontalScrollView which has infinite width! Thus, It can't set its weight.

So, You need a to put your Table in a ScrollView (vertical) then inside the Table there is the HorizontalScrollView. Also, you need to add height m width attribute after changing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/routine_heading"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/routine_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:fillViewport="false">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tlGridTable"
                android:stretchColumns="*">
                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="10-10:50"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="10:50-11:40"
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="11:40-12:30"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="12:30-1:20"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="2:35-3:20"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="3:20-4:00"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/cell"
                        android:text="4:00-4:50"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                </TableRow>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Recommended to use a ListView/RecyclerView with a adapter for this
>   kind of works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scrolling table, you generally use a `ListView` + an `Adapter`.

Each item of the Adapter should create a "row" of the "table".

Using a `RecyclerView` could help with the vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Add Table layout below Scrollview (into child view) like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/routine_heading"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/app_name"
      android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
      />
  <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
      android:fillViewport="false"
      android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
      android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
      >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlGridTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
      <HorizontalScrollView
          android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
          >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:text=""
              />

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="10-10:50"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="10:50-11:40"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="11:40-12:30"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="12:30-1:20"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="2:35-3:20"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="3:20-4:00"
              />
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:text="4:00-4:50"
              />
        </TableRow>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</TableLayout>
```